# Convert docx to string in Python

Tags: string, text, comparison, python-docx

I am trying to read .docx file in python using:

```
file1 = docx.Document('C:\\text.docx') #Reader object
```

From here how can I convert it into string? I am actually trying to compare two word documents. My approach is to convert both into string variables and then compare.
Please do suggest if there is any other way I can do the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It does not answer your actual question but your objective, comparing the word documents. [Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/python) supports the feature to compare word documents. Currently, it only supports the comparison from cloud storage(Aspose storage, Amazon S3, DropBox, FTP Storage, Google Drive and Windows Azure Storage). But in near future, we have a plan to compare documents from streams(request body).

```
# For complete examples and data files, please go to https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud/aspose-words-cloud-python
# Import module
import asposewordscloud
import asposewordscloud.models.requests
import os
from shutil import copyfile

# Get your credentials from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud (free registration is required).
words_api = asposewordscloud.WordsApi(app_sid='xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx',app_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
words_api.api_client.configuration.host = 'https://api.aspose.cloud'

remoteFolder = 'Temp/CompareDocument'
localFolder = 'C:/Temp'
localName1 = 'compareTestDoc1.docx'
localName2 = 'compareTestDoc2.docx'
remoteName1 = 'TestCompareDocument1.docx'
remoteName2 = 'TestCompareDocument2.docx'
dest_name = 'C:/Temp/TestCompareDocumentOut.docx'

# upload files to storage
response_upload1 = words_api.upload_file(asposewordscloud.models.requests.UploadFileRequest(open(localFolder + '/' + localName1,'rb'),remoteFolder + '/' + remoteName1))
response_upload2 = words_api.upload_file(asposewordscloud.models.requests.UploadFileRequest(open(localFolder + '/' + localName2,'rb'),remoteFolder + '/' + remoteName2))

# compare documents
requestCompareData = asposewordscloud.CompareData(author='author', comparing_with_document=remoteFolder + '/' + remoteName2)
request = asposewordscloud.models.requests.CompareDocumentRequest(name=remoteName1, compare_data=requestCompareData, folder=remoteFolder, dest_file_name=remoteFolder + '/TestCompareDocumentOut.docx')
result = words_api.compare_document(request)
copyfile(result, dest_name)
print("Result {}".format(result))
```

P.S: I'm developer evangelist at Aspose.